# similar to .get() attribute for IndexedParam or IndexedVar

Tags: python-2.7, pyomo

I need to check if a variable's index exist,while calling a Constraint initialization and if  it does not exist i want to set the variable's value to 0.In a python dictionary you can do so with something like that: dict.get('not-a-key',0).Is there something similar for Pyomo objects?

Answer (score 0):

We haven't added this method because one might expect to use it to return a new variable (that would not be owned by the container, because the `get` method does not modify a dictionary). Perhaps something like the `setdefault` method would make more sense here, but this is also not something that is currently built into the modeling interface.

One piece of functionality that you might be able to use is that Pyomo will implicitly construct a new variable object at a particular index if that index was added to the variable's indexing set after the initial declaration. Example:

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x_index = Set(initialize=[1])
model.x = Var(model.x_index)
model.x[1]   # OK
model.x[2]   # KeyError
model.x_index.add(2)
model.x[2]   # OK (implicitly creates this object on the fly)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I actually solved this problem by creating a dictionary with the values of the variable and then using that in my function.